# Redefining a function to be a partial of itself -- why illegal?

Tags: python, lambda

```python
def f(x):
    return x

f = lambda : f(5)

f()

=> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 4, in <lambda>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I can see intuitively why this doesn't work...it's sort of a circular reference. Specifically what rule in Python is it breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @U12-Forward posted, the reason you create a circular reference is the late binding of the lambda. By the time it calls `f(5)` it's already referring to itself.

If your intent is to call your original `f()` you can force the binding with:

```
f = lambda f=f: f(5)
```

and calling `f()` will return `5` because that's what the original `f()` does.

Comment: Ah yes, the late binding is the key. Apparently late binding in closures is a common gotcha in Python. https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Kinda weird how you can do that hack of giving it a default argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're overriding the function name. On the `lambda` line:

```
f = lambda : f(5)
```

It becomes a recursion, it does `f(5)` which calls itself. The only reason it didn't call it self over and over again (recursion) is because you're using `lambda:`, that takes no arguments, so if you did:

```
f = lambda: f()
```

You would get a `RecursionError`.

A `lambda` is essentially a function, that `lambda` could be translated to:

```
def f():
    return f()
```

Answer (score 3):

The `f` inside `lambda: f(5)` is a *free* variable. (It is not defined in the scope of the function; it's value is found outside the function scope.) The current value of `f` is not used to define the resulting function; the value of `f` will be looked up when the function is called, and the value of `f` can (and in this case does) change between the function being defined and the function being called.

When you finally call `f()`, the value of `f` is the same function, but now you attempt to call it with the argument that the *original*, not the current, function bound to the name `f` expected, resulting in a `TypeError`.